# Can I avoid Event Hub duplicates by plugging it with Service Bus Sessions?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

Our application architecture is the following :

**Third party event hub ==> our azure function ==> our event hub ==> our event hub capture.**

The issue is that we are [getting duplicates messages quite often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401913/azure-functions-with-event-hub-trigger-writes-duplicate-messages), and we don't any primary key in the data.

I could read online that **Service Bus Sessions** [could avoid this duplicate issue.](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428)

[image]

> Azure Service Bus now supports sessions, so you can do in order queue
> processing with service bus queues and topics in addition to Event
> Hubs listed below. Service Bus Sessions provide the added benefit of
> reprocessing failures individually instead of in batches. While Event
> Hubs can guarantee order as show below, if a partition lock is lost
> the in-order batch could resume in another instance causing
> duplicates. Consider using Service Bus Sessions if this is an issue.
> Both provide at-least-once delivery guarantees.

I am new to Azure and streaming cloud architecture in general.

**My question is the following :**

- **Could Service Bus Session be plugged in our current architecture?**
- **Or is it rather a competing service of our event hub ?**

I am not sure we would be ready to give up on our event hub now as we have just invested resources implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Bus sessions doesn't really guarantee that there will be no duplicates, as it continues to be "at least once delivery", however service bus has a feature called [duplicate detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection) that basically helps to prevent duplicates for message **coming** to the namespace,it won't help for outgoing duplicates (mostly caused by transient network issues).

Besides what I mentioned above, the behavior you are describing doesn't sound normal. Yes, Event Hubs could have duplicates but it should not be happening quite too often, if that's the case I would suggest focusing on the root cause for whatever is causing so many duplicates. (you can open a MS support ticket for some help on finding this)
But if those duplicates aren't that many, then I suggest you make your consumer resilient to duplicates as suggested by the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus and Azure Event Hub are [two different products](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services). You cannot use a feature of one product with another.

Instead you can try to find a way to identify duplicate messages. If a message itself has no unique property, then you can try creating a digest or hash of the message based on the properties. Then keep track of the hash for the message retention period of Azure Event Hub. When a new message comes in, create hash of the message and compare with tracked hashes to check for uniqueness.